# Web page appears too "zoomed in" in non-retina/HD screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

I have an issue with the way web pages are appearing on non-retina screens. I'm developing a website on a 5k imac, and the appearance on the site when viewed on the imac is perfect. However, upon viewing the page on a standard definition laptop screen, I noticed that the content appears too large and "zoomed in". When I zoom out to 90%, the scale/proportions appear much better. What I would like to know is how can I maintain the scale on the retina screen, while having the page appear at "zoom 90%" when viewed on non HD screens?

Comment: What metadata you have set for view-port?

Comment: this: <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">